# Vue 3 VueX mapGetters возврощает undefined. Как с этим боротся?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, state

У меня есть компонент. И глобальный `state` `vuex`.

Когда я из компонента вызываю

```
...mapGetters('addPerson', {
    personStyle: 'personStyle',
    personForm: 'personForm',
}),
```

То оно возвращает `undefined`.

Кто то может мне помочь разобраться с этим?

Вот сам код.

***Компонент***

```
<template>
    <div class="edit-div" id="editPopup">
        
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
    import BreezeValidationErrors from '@/Components/ValidationErrors'

    export default {
        components: {
            BreezeValidationErrors
        },
        methods: {
            
        },
        updated() {
            console.log(this.personStyle)
            console.log(this.$store)
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.personStyle)
            console.log(this.$store)
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters('addPerson', {
                personStyle: 'personStyle',
                personForm: 'personForm',
            }),
        },
    }
</script>
```

***State***

```
const state = {
    personStyle: {
        display: 'none',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
    },
    personForm: []
}
const getters = {
    personStyle: (state) => state.personStyle,
    personForm: (state) => state.personForm
}
const mutations = {
    setStyle: (state, style) => {
        state.personStyle = style;
    },
    setForm: (state, form) => {
        state.personForm = form;
    }
}
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    mutations,
    getters,
}
```

А модули прикручиваются так.

```
import addPerson from "@/store/addPerson";
//...............

import Vuex from "vuex";

const modules = {
    addPerson,
}
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если `...mapGetters('addPerson', ['personStyle', 'personForm'])`?

Comment: @yar85 пробывал, уже надоело мне `Vue`))). 3 часа уже вожусь с ним.

Comment: @yar85 А у него вообще есть какой то `cache`? Может как то с этим связано ?

Comment: Кэшируются только результаты возвращаемые геттерами. Проблема связана скорее с тем, что в сторе (а не в компоненте) эти геттеры не регистрируются. Я бы проверил такой вариант, заглянув в свойство `modules` экземпляра `Store`. Еще в третьей версии вьюэкса я сталкивался с какими-то проблемами namespaced геттеров, имеет смысл попробовать модуль подключить как обычный.

Comment: Если без namespaced заработает, то искать причины надо в разрешении имен геттеров. Если не заработает - то искать их в регистрации модуля/свойств в экземпляре стора. Как-то так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема похоже именно в импорте конфигурации модуля (что-то не так с конфигом Vuex), т.к. почти тот же самый код, но без импортов - работает корректно:

```js
const addPerson = {
  namespaced: true, 
  state: {
    personStyle: {
      display: 'none',
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
    },
    personForm: [],
  },
  getters: {
    personStyle: (state) => state.personStyle,
    personForm: (state) => state.personForm
  },
  mutations: {
    setStyle: (state, style) => {
      state.personStyle = style;
    },
    setForm: (state, form) => {
      state.personForm = form;
    },
  },
};

const app = Vue.createApp({
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapGetters('addPerson', ['personStyle', 'personForm']), 
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.personStyle); 
    console.log('has addPerson module: ' + this.$store.hasModule('addPerson')); 
  }, 
});
app.use(Vuex.createStore({ modules: { addPerson }}));
app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@4.0.2/dist/vuex.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pre>{{ personStyle }}</pre>
  <pre>{{ personForm }}</pre>
</div>
```

Что делать в таких ситуациях, как бороться:

- проверять что фактически импортируется (выводом в консоль)
- сверять схему своих объектов конфигурации (которые передаются конструкторам библиотек Vue и Vuex) с документацией
- перезапускать devserver при изменениях в импортах :)

##### Upd.:

Причина проблемы оказалась в схеме объекта конфига Vuex - в экспортируемом объекте было пропущено свойство `state`.
То есть, при выполнении рекомендаций из списка выше, помог бы второй пункт.

Comment: Без отдельного компонента - для краткости. Дополнительный компонент ничего не изменит, потому что экземпляр хранилища и свойство `$store` регистрируются глобально (ссылаются на один и тот же экземпляр во всех компонентах вебприложения, включая корневой).

Comment: Может здесь версия другая? я в ՝export default՝ кроме ՝namespaced, mutations, getters՝ добавил еще и `state` и заработало. Но в варианте как здесь у вас опять не работает. Здесь какая версия `vuex` подключается ?

Comment: @RazGalstyan, да, такое может быть. Здесь подключаются актуальные продакшн версии обеих библиотек: в данный момент это Vue 2.6.14 (не 3.*) и Vuex 3.6.2 (не 4.*). А нужны именно самые распоследние? Какие используются в твоем проекте?

Comment: Хм, а почему вью не третья, она же вроде уже прод... может unpkg "тормозит". Через некоторое время попробую с 3.* и дополню ответ.

Comment: У меня и `Vue` и `Vuex` последние версии.

Comment: `vue@3.2.11` , `vuex@4.0.2`

Comment: @RazGalstyan, обновил пример до указанных версий - все равно не ломается :) Советую сверить свой код с примером (с поправкой на импорты), и прологировать в консоль объекты конфигов непосредственно перед их передачей в конструкторы... в твоем проекте явно что-то не так именно на этапе инициализации экземпляров. По крайней мере, я не вижу тут других возможных причин.

Comment: @RazGalstyan, или добавление (в экспортируемый объект) свойства `state` уже все починило? Я не совсем понял, решена проблема или еще нет :)

Comment: Я добавил `state` в экспорт, и начало работать. Но в доке не нашел это. не знаю после обновления что будет)))). Сейчас да уже решилась проблема. Спасибо.